# OpenSSL PKCS#11 failed loading private key

Tags: opensuse, openssl, smartcard

I am running OpenSUSE LEAP15.1 and a seeing the following when trying to use a Nitrokey USB HSM:

```
engine "pkcs11" set.
Unable to load module (null)
Unable to load module (null)
PKCS11_get_private_key returned NULL
cannot load CA private key from engine
140396815820608:error:81065401:libp11:pkcs11_CTX_load:Unable to load PKCS#11 module:p11_load.c:77:
140396815820608:error:26096080:engine routines:ENGINE_load_private_key:failed loading private key:crypto/engine/eng_pkey.c:78:
unable to load CA private key
unable to load certificates
```

However, PKCS is functional:

```
 pkcs11-tool --test

Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
C_SeedRandom() and C_GenerateRandom():
  seeding (C_SeedRandom) not supported
  seems to be OK
Digests:
  all 4 digest functions seem to work
  MD5: OK
  SHA-1: OK
  RIPEMD160: OK
Signature: not a R/W session, skipping signature tests
Verify: not a R/W session, skipping verify tests
Key unwrap: not a R/W session, skipping key unwrap tests
Decryption: not a R/W session, skipping decryption tests
No errors

  pkcs15-tool -D                                                                                                                           
Using reader with a card: Nitrokey Nitrokey HSM (DENK99999999         ) 00 00                                                                                            
PKCS#15 Card [SmartCard-HSM]:                                                                                                                                               
        Version        : 0                                                                                                                                                  
        Serial number  : DENK999999                                                                                                                                       
        Manufacturer ID: www.CardContact.de                                                                                                                                 
        Flags          :                                                                                                                                                    

PIN [UserPIN]       
etc.
etc.
etc.
```

`libpkcs11-helper1` ,`openssl-ibmpkcs11` ,`pkcs11-helper` and  `openssl-engine-libp11` packages are installed and my openssl.conf file has the correct settings:

```
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section

[pkcs11_section]
#engine_id = pkcs11 #Note: I have tried both with and without this setting
dynamic_path= /usr/lib64/engines-1.1/pkcs11.so
MODULE_PATH = /usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so
#init = 0 #Note: I have tried both with and without this setting
```

And I have verified the files exist:

```
> ls /usr/lib64/engines-1.1/pkcs11.so
/usr/lib64/engines-1.1/pkcs11.so
> ls /usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so
/usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

Comment: any luck getting the pkcs11 engine to work?

Comment: @Jared sorry for the delay. No.  I ended up dumping openSUSE and using another OS instead. Seems to be something specific to openSUSE but I had no luck finding anyone (here or elsewhere) to help.